# Using resumable.js from Dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop, resumablejs

I am trying to use [resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js) from Dart with this code:

```
var rs = new JS.JsObject(JS.context['Resumable'], [new JS.JsObject.jsify({
  'target':context.server+'/upload'
})]);

files.forEach((file) {
  rs.callMethod("addFile",[file]);
});
```

`files` variable is defined as `List<File>` (`dart.html.File`). When I check properties of `rs` object with these two lines:

```
JS.context["console"].callMethod("log",[rs['opts']]);
JS.context["console"].callMethod("log",[rs['files']]);
```

I find that `rs.opts` are initialized correctly, but `rs.files` always contains instances of `ResumableFile` with length 1. I guess that it is because method addFile expects parameter to be instance of Javascript `File` but it gets instanceof `dart:html.File`.

Do you have any idea how to convert `dart:html.File` to Javascript `File` or how to pass argument to [resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js)?

I know that I can alternatively use methods `assignBrowse` and `assignDrop`, but I would like to stick to my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [JsObject.fromBrowserObject](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:js.JsObject#id_JsObject-fromBrowserObject) to get the underlying js object.

```dart
files.forEach((file) {
  rs.callMethod("addFile",[new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(file)]);
});
```